# Checking OS compatibility

Tags: c++, cross-platform, compatibility

I have written an application in C++ without using system specific libraries. I know that if I want to obtain executable binaries for instance for Windows, I need to build my code on this platform. But I am looking for a way to check if my executable is compatible with all windows versions or with all linux distributions. Is there any automatic way to check it? Or I am obliged to check it on my own?

Comment: do you mean checking that the output of the build (the executable) is compatible between platforms? if this is the case, then no it isn't. Linux uses ELF, but windows uses COFF.

Comment: My question is: can I check if my windows-specific executalble car run on systems between Win XP - Win 10 or linux-specific can run on all distributions?

Comment: "executable is compatible with all windows versions" - achieving this is trivial, you just need to build with correct platform toolset and WinSDK configuration. "executable is compatible with all linux distributions"  - not possible, you can only target particular variants

Comment: Sure. But is three any way to.. I don't know.. list compatible distros somehow? I mean, to chcek if my executalble can run on Ubuntu, Debian, Mint and do on.

Comment: You will need to set up park of VMs, running every distro variant that you plan to support (note that you will need to target particular versions of each distro, not just "Mint"), and upload / build your application on those machines and run tests after every change.

Comment: You should do the same even with Windows builds. If a program relies on features in newer Windows versions then it won't be compatible with older versions. If it static links to newer APIs, it won't even run on older versions. But if it dynamic links to newer APIs, it will run but it MAY OR MAY NOT function correctly at runtime. You just don't know until you test it on every version you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends on the version of the libc/libstdc++ you are building with.

If you create an executable, unless you link it statically, it will actually be linked against several system libraries. Those libraries version will determine which system your application will be compatible with.

So unfortunately, there is no way to tell, except testing on several systems directly…

And to do so, some systems exist, ex:

https://distrotest.net/